# Skipping one iteration of for loop

Tags: c

Both the code and output are attached.

Basically it's skipping my input for the second time around.  Like I start the code and it lets me input an option, then skips the input for the second time around and just goes to the default case of the switch.

Then third time it will allow me to input.  Can't figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ohh and this is an assignment, so I have to have the input be within the menu() prototype and I have to use a switch to evaluate in main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char menu(void);

int main(void){
    int a;
    char op;
    for (a = 1; a != 0;) {
        op = menu();
        switch (op) {
            case 'a':
                printf("youre in a\n\n");
                break;
            case 'e':
                printf("youre in e\n\n");
                break;
            case 'p':
                printf("youre in p\n\n");
                break;
            case 's':
                printf("youre is s\n\n");
                break;
            case 'm':
                printf("youre in m\n\n");
                break;
            case 'x':
                printf("youre in x\n\n");
                a = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid entry. Please choose valid option.\n\n");
                break;
        }//end switch
    }//end while
    return 0;
}//end main

//menu prototype
char menu(void){
    char option;
    printf("-------------------------------");
    printf("\nWelcome To Virtual Art Gallery");
    printf("\n-------------------------------");
    printf("\nMenu - Select on of the following options:");
    printf("\npress 'a': To add a painting");
    printf("\npress 'e': To erase a painting");
    printf("\npress 'p': To print data for all paintings");
    printf("\npress 's': To print data for special paintings");
    printf("\npress 'm': To modify data for a painting");
    printf("\npress 'x': To exit the program");
    printf("\noption: ? ");
    option = getchar();
    return option;
}//end menu()
```

[Here's the output that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6yft.png)

Comment: Mind the newline.

Comment: Tip: Create more informative error messages `printf("Invalid entry code %d. Please choose valid option.\n\n", op);`

Comment: Rather than post/link pictures of text, it is more useful to post text as text in the question.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  - I was thinking that might be the case but I can not figure out how to correct it

Comment: @DavidJones Check for it and ignore. Or use alternative input functions.

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c", &option);` to skip optional white space, including newlines, and then read a character.  Beware EOF.  Or use `int c; … while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && isspace(c)) ;` (using `<ctypes.h>` to get `isspace()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following line right after your call to `op = menu()` in `main`:

```
    printf("op = \'%c\'\n", op);
```

You will notice that `op` is actually a new line character for most inputs. This is because `getchar` is consuming latent newlines in `stdin` rather than the characters you're actually entering.

Some workarounds:

1. Use `getchar` in a loop that removes all newlines first:

   ```
   do
   {
       option = getchar();
   }
   while(isspace(option));
   ```
2. Use `scanf` with a space before the `"%c"` format specifier:

   ```
   scanf(" %c", &option);
   ```

   A single space before a `scanf` format string will automatically consume any latent newlines in `stdin`.